# How to get bounding box from object detection of TensorFlowJS?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I'm using this [object detection model](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/tfjs-model/ssd_mobilenet_v2/1/default/1). And I'd like to get bounding box, class labe and score. I think this model returns bounding box and so on. however it's returns diferent results.

**My code**

```
function getMethods(o) {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(o))
        .filter(m => 'function' === typeof o[m]);
}

const model = await tf.loadGraphModel("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/tfjs-model/ssd_mobilenet_v2/1/default/1", {fromTFHub: true});
console.log("Get methods");
console.log(getMethods(model));

const cat = document.getElementById('cat');
let tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(cat);
tensor = tf.cast(tensor, 'int32');
let y_pred = await model.executeAsync({'image_tensor': tensor.expandDims(0)});
console.log('Predictions: ');
console.log(y_pred);
```

**Results**

```
(12) ["constructor", "findIOHandler", "load", "loadSync", "save", "predict", "normalizeInputs", "normalizeOutputs", "execute", "executeAsync", "convertTensorMapToTensorsMap", "dispose"]

Predictions
[
  {
    "kept": false,
    "isDisposedInternal": false,
    "shape": [
      1,
      1917,
      90
    ],
    "dtype": "float32",
    "size": 172530,
    "strides": [
      172530,
      90
    ],
    "dataId": {
      "id": 1959
    },
    "id": 1188,
    "rankType": "3",
    "scopeId": 1382
  },
  {
    "kept": false,
    "isDisposedInternal": false,
    "shape": [
      1,
      1917,
      1,
      4
    ],
    "dtype": "float32",
    "size": 7668,
    "strides": [
      7668,
      4,
      4
    ],
    "dataId": {
      "id": 2019
    },
    "id": 1239,
    "rankType": "4",
    "scopeId": 1475
  }
]
```

If I get bounding box, class labe and score, How should I change my code?

Comment: Are you calling model.detect() anywhere? This returns an array of objects with the property bbox

Comment: Hello Joe. No I didn't call model.detect(). I checked methods of model. It does not have detect(). I updated my question.

Comment: What does `console.log(y_pred.dataSync())` output?

Comment: It returned error. Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: y_pred.dataSync is not a function

Answer (score 0):

each model is different, this one is on tfhub model page: https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/ssd_mobilenet_v2/2 - you can see what each tensor in output result is

anyhow, model returns all possible scores, classes and boxes without any filtering - which means you need to post-process those results, best using `tf.image.nonMaxSuppressionAsync()` so you can filter by minimum score and get only boxes you want back

then match box indexes with index of class tensor output to match box with class

you can look up reference implementation at https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/master/coco-ssd/src/index.ts, key function is `infer`

Answer (score 0):

There is a ready made code proovided by Paul Van Eck (IBM Developer) channel from YouTube (code snippet works for me, but as a model not good):

```
const scores = y_pred[0].dataSync();
const numBoxesFound = y_pred[0].shape[1];
const numClassesFound = y_pred[0].shape[2];

const maxScores = [];
const classes = [];

// for each bounding box returned
for (let i = 0; i < numBoxesFound; i++) {
   let maxScore = -1;
   let classIndex = -1;

   // find the class with the highest score
   for (let j = 0; j < numClassesFound; j++) {
   if (scores[i * numClassesFound + j] > maxScore) {
       maxScore = scores[i * numClassesFound + j];
       classIndex = j;
   }
}

   maxScores[i] = maxScore;
   classes[i] = classIndex;
}  
 
const boxes = tf.tensor2d(y_pred[1].dataSync(), [y_pred[1].shape[1], y_pred[1].shape[3]]);
const indexTensor = tf.image.nonMaxSuppression(boxes, maxScores, maxNumBoxes, 0.5, 0.5);  
const indexes = indexTensor.dataSync();

const count = indexes.length;
const objects = [];

for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   const bbox = [];

   for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
   bbox[j] = rrr[1].dataSync()[indexes[i] * 4 + j];
}

const minY = bbox[0] * image_height; //  <= width & height you can get it by gm nodejs module
const minX = bbox[1] * image_width;
const maxY = bbox[2] * image_height;
const maxX = bbox[3] * image_width;

objects.push({
  bbox: [minX, minY, maxX, maxY],
  label: labels[classes[indexes[i]]],
  score: maxScores[indexes[i]]
});
}
console.log(objects);
// output:
[
   {
       bbox: [
           25.680667877197266,
           991.999267578125,
           2295.833375930786,
           3062.655055999756
       ],
       label: 'background',
       score: 0.900220513343811
   }
]
```